# Customize openAM login page using client-name

Tags: authentication, openam, customizing

From this article: http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/install-guide/index.html#chap-custom-ui

It seem we also can have customize page based on client-name (defualt is html): 
suffix_client-locale-language_client-locale-territory/services/realm/client-name/file-name

May I know how we pass the request parameter to login url (openam/UI/Login) ?

Please guide.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The 'client' header is 'User-Agent' HTTP request header.

-Bernhard